# PHP mail(From) cyrrilic encoding

Tags: php, encoding

I have problem with cyrillic in the (From) part of the email. I had the same problem with the subject but i fixed it like that.

```
$subject = '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=';
```

And these are my heders.

```
 $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
```

And still when i pass cyrillic , i get something like **РЇРІРѕСЂ** .

```
$headers = "From: асдафсддс <email@test.test>\r\n";
```

My from is something like this.

Comment: The $subject is `utf-8` encoded?

Comment: Yes it's utf-8, but i have problem with the From .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use

```
$headers = "From: =?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($fromname)."?= <email@test.test>\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Email headers can exclusively contain ASCII characters. That's the reason you need to encode the subject, and it's the reason you also need to encode the `From` header. To do so, best use [`mb_encode_mimeheader`](http://php.net/mb_encode_mimeheader). See the examples in its documentation.